# Code coverage is not getting generated. Previously I used to get it properly, now they upgraded to rhel 8. Now, no code coverage is coming at all

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I've been generating code coverage using jacoco cli from adding this line to script and generate .exec file

export JAVA_OPTS=" -javaagent:/home/im/druthik/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/im/druthik/im_gui1.exec ....

It's generating the .exec file successfully, but every time of a constant size 2668k and for each session it is appending this size to the existing .exec file. And when I generate report from this .exec file I see all zero's in report. Previously when I did on rhel 7 server I was able to get it...now I'm using rhel 8. Is it OS causing the issue. Can some one help me figure this out?

I tried updating the jacoco binary version. But it's of no use